# How much space will duplicate text take stored in a varchar type column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand the space each varchar character would take but do you guys know how it adds up for each row? Especially, is there any intelligence if I am saving same varchar data in each row?

For example: for the following rows

```
Column1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
```

Assume that if 'value1' takes 7 bytes of space - would it take 5 * 7 = 35 bytes to store all the rows?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2299190/342156

Comment: Thanks Simen, hard to belive they won't allow the page compression in standard version. reading the page compression, not sure how it escaped from my search. :-)

Comment: Actually, it will take 5 * (7 + 4) bytes - at least 4 bytes overhead for each entry. The real number of bytes for the overhead depends on a lot of issues - but since it's a variable length type, you have 2 bytes for the length, and you typically also have at least 2 bytes for "general" overhead (things like whether the row is NULL or not, and more).

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server will not compress your data. Depending on what version you are running it is an option.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea about the size? i.e. what is the result of this compression?